# Applying adverb to colon operator

Tags: kdb, k

Please help me with colon `:` operator, I'm stuck on how it works. It works as an assignment, assignment through `x+:1`, global assignment/view `::`, I/O `0:`, `1:`, to return value from the middle of the function `:r`, and to get an unary form of operator `#:`.

But what happend if one apply an adverb to it? I tried this way:

```
$ q
KDB+ 3.6 2019.04.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems
q)(+')[100;2 3 4]
102 103 104
q)(:')[x;2 3 4]
'x
  [0]  (:')[x;2 3 4]
            ^
q)(:')[100;2 3 4]
2 3 4
```

I expect evaluations in order: `x:2`, then `x:3`, then `x:4`. To get `x:4` as a result. But I've got an error. And also `:'` works with a number `100` for some unknown reason.

What `:'` is actually doing?

```
q)parse "(:')[100;2 3 4]"
(';:)
100
2 3 4
```

Parsing didn't shed much light to me, so I'm asking for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modified by an iterator (also known as an adverb in q speak), `:` behaves just like any other binary operator. In your example

```
q)(:')[100;2 3 4]
2 3 4
```

an atom `100` is extended to a conformant list `100 100 100` and then `:` is applied to elements of the two lists pairwise. The final result is returned. It might look confusing (`:` tries to modify a constant value, really?) but if you compare this to any other binary operator and notice that they never modify their operands but return a *result* of expression everything should click into place.

For example, compare

```
q)+'[100; 2 3 4]
102 103 104
```

and

```
q)(:')[100;2 3 4]
2 3 4
```

In both cases an a temporary vector `100 100 100` is created implicitly and an operator is applied to it and `2 3 4`. So the former is semantically equivalent to

```
(t[0]+2;t[1]+2;t[2]+4)
```

and the latter to

```
(t[0]:2;t[1]:2;t[2]:4)
```

where `t` is that temporary vector.

This explains why `(:')[x;2 3 4]` gives an error -- if `x` doesn't exist kdb can't extend it to a list.

Comment: Tricky thing, a temporary vector that is created implicitly. Now it's clear why it works with `x:1` or with the same length vector `x:1 2 3` initialized previously. Great thanks!

Comment: Please take my words about implicit creation of a vector with a pinch of salt. Kdb may or may not use various optimisations depending on operators. I don't know what happens *internally* when kdb needs to extend an atom to a list but it *behaves* as if a temp object is created.

Comment: Totally agree - kdb could be very tricky in its optimizations. With memory profiling I hope it could be possible to indirectly confirm some of assumptions. But a question how to profile q programs is still open for me.